# Why does this bit shift work?

Tags: c, networking, ip

I was trying to send an ICMP packet, so I wrote the following code:

```
IP *construct_ip_hdr(struct sockaddr_in *src, struct sockaddr_in *dst)
{
    IP *iph = malloc(sizeof(IP));
    if (!iph)
     {
            perror("malloc");
            return NULL;
     }

    memset(iph, 0, sizeof(IP));
    iph->version |= IP_VERSION;
    iph->version |= DEFAULT_IHL;

    iph->tos = TOS;
    iph->tot_len = htons(DEFAULT_TOTAL_LEN + ICMP_SIZE);
    iph->id = htons(ID);
    iph->frag_off |= (1 << 14);
    iph->ttl = DEFAULT_TTL;
    iph->proto = DEFAULT_PROTO;
    iph->src = src->sin_addr.s_addr;
    iph->dst = dst->sin_addr.s_addr;
    iph->chksum = htons(calculate_ip_chksum(iph));

    return iph;
}
```

I tried sending the packet, however it was unsuccessful. I examined the packet in Wireshark. It showed that the flags field of the IP header (which I combined with the fragment offset field) was completely zeroed out. Later on, I made a mistake writing and replaced the `1 << 14` with `2 << 6`. When I examined the packet sent in Wireshark, it showed that I had sent the ICMP packet correctly. However, I don't understand why `2 << 6` works and why `1 << 14` doesn't when setting the flags field of the IP header.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I don't know if 2 << 6 would work correctly... however perhaps the value of `iph->frag_off` needs to be in *network byte order*

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Endianness would be my guess too - `flags` are [in octet #2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header), whereas the fragment offset is octet #2 and #3 - given it's in big endian order, `flags` are in the low byte.